# Reftex citation as footnote in orgmode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to have a function that insert a citation with format “First_Author (1998)” using reftex, add an org footnote and fill the description with format “All_Authors, “title”, journal (1998)”. My current unworking atempt is:

```
(defun cite-footnote()
(interactive)
(let (ENTRY)
  (setq ENTRY (reftex-citation t))
  (message (reftex-format-citation ENTRY "%A (%y)"))
  (org-footnote-new)
  (insert (reftex-format-citation ENTRY "%a, “%t”, %j, (%y)"))
  ))
```

The problem is that the output of `reftex-citation` is not what is expected a first argument for `reftex-format-citation`. What would be the proper combination of commands?

Comment: org-footnote-new surely, not org-footOnote-new?

Answer (score 1):

I have hacked reftex so that it can insert references into asciidoc or markdown, which is similar to what you want.

https://github.com/phillord/phil-emacs-packages/blob/master/greycite.el

It really is a hack -- I fills my needs and I never got around to doing it properly, but it should give you the idea.

There appears to be another solution here.

http://blog.modelworks.ch/?p=379

Comment: I am using something similar to what you posted as alternative. My issue here is mostly about inserting to citation while prompting only once.